# Populating table with cte using sequence (NEXT VALUE FOR) SQL Server Managment Studio

Tags: sql-server, sequence, populate

I'm trying to populate a table.

Here is a code

```
WITH cte_Filters AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.AutoIncrementNumberSequence, 1, 5),
               (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.AutoIncrementNumberSequence, 8, 2),
               (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.AutoIncrementNumberSequence, 3, 1),
               (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.AutoIncrementNumberSequence, 5, 7),
               (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.AutoIncrementNumberSequence, 6, 5)
    ) q1 (ID, ProductID, TagID)
)
--insert into dbo.Filters(FilterID, ProductID, TagID)
SELECT s.* 
FROM cte_Filters AS s
LEFT JOIN dbo.Filters AS d ON s.ID = d.FilterID
WHERE d.FilterId IS NULL;
```

I get this error:

> Line 22: NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, derived tables or return statements.

I understand that it's because I use NEXT VALUE FOR in subquery but I don't have a clue, how to rebuild it in the way it would be out of subquery. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your query? Assuming that you did not reset your sequence how can this condition (`LEFT JOIN dbo.Filters AS d ON s.ID = d.FilterID`) ever match?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, I am not sure at all as to what you are trying to achive but you can try the following:

```
DECLARE @Blah AS TABLE( ID INT, ProductID INT, TagID INT )
INSERT INTO @Blah( ProductID, TagID ) VALUES( 1, 5 ), ( 8, 2 ) etc..
INSERT INTO Filters( .... )
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.AutoIncrementNumberSequence , ProductID, TagID
FROM @Blah AS s
```